# How geolocation.getCurrentPosition return value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, geolocation

I am using getCurrentPosition to get local latitude and longitude. I know this function is asynchronous, just wondering how to return latitude and longitude value that can be accessed by other functions?

```
    function getGeo() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCurrentLoc)
    }

    function getCurrentLoc(data) {
        var lat,lon;
        lat=data.coords.latitude;
        lon=data.coords.longitude;
        getLocalWeather(lat,lon)
        initMap(lat,lon)
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

I would suggest you wrapping it in a promise:

```
function getPosition() {
    // Simple wrapper
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej);
    });
}

async function main() {
    var position = await getPosition();  // wait for getPosition to complete
    console.log(position);
}

main();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/zr8L57sL/

ES6 version:

```
function getPosition() {
    // Simple wrapper
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej);
    });
}

function main() {
    getPosition().then(console.log); // wait for getPosition to complete
}

main();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/90129LoL/

Comment: simple and clean! Thank you!!

Comment: Excellent indeed! The 'return new Promise' method is a great way to work with callbacks within a function (in this case geolocation.getCurrentPosition) where normal .then handling falls short